# Using multiple TF-IDF matrices on a classification task

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a dataframe with a certain number of columns of type text. Let's say column A has the name (random names that cannot be used as keys but resemble sentences) and B has its description(a bigger chunk of text). Whilst training, I would want a higher weightage for the column A than column B. Using a single TF-IDF matrix will make it quite homogenous i.e words from A and B will get mixed up and be considered identical in terms of the importance. What could be a possible solution to implement this. I was thinking of multiple TF-IDF matrices.

**Edit:** After some brain storming, it looks like multiple tf-idf is not an appropriate solution as the vocabulary set will be different. Any other approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't necessarily do that, and it's not recommended even if you find a way/hack to do it. One hack would be to ensemble multiple models, weighted - with one feature per model. This is not a tested approach, so proceed with caution.

Do Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) to see how it affects your accuracy + precision + recall. Also, rank your features using random forests benchmarks to be able to see which feature gives your model more variance.